# XeTeX problem: no italics with i+tilde

Tags: xetex, tilde

When I use `\emph{\~\i}` to create an i with tilde in XeTeX (using Linux Libertine), the i is not typeset in italics. Does anyone know a workaround?

You can see a MWE here:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}

\emph{G\~\i k\~uy\~u}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!
Thomas

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: On my system I have to call the font as `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` and this works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Too long for a comment.</sub>

If I change the font to `Linux Libertine O` (OpenType variant), then it works for both XeTeX and LuaTeX. Also the character can be specified directly:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
  \emph{G\~\i k\~uy\~u  ĩ}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]